# I want to call glBegin and glEnd once per Frame

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

As in the title I would like to be able to call glBegin and glEnd only once per frame/update as I have both heard and am experiencing that if you call it multiple times per update it slows drastically.

This is my code for my render function:

```
GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
    int x = 0;

    while (x < World.BLOCKS_WIDTH - 1) {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < World.BLOCKS_HEIGHT - 1) {

            if( x * World.BLOCK_SIZE  <= Display.getHeight() ||  y * World.BLOCK_SIZE <= 
                Display.getWidth() ||  x * World.BLOCK_SIZE >= 0 || 
                y * World.BLOCK_SIZE >= 0 ) {

            blocks.b[data.blocks[x][y]].draw(x + Main.PosX, y + Main.PosY);

            }

            y++;
        }
        x++;

}
```

any help appreciated.

this is my block class:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslatef(Xa * World.BLOCK_SIZE, Ya * World.BLOCK_SIZE, 0);
    //GL11.glRotatef(0, 0, 1, 0);
    //GL11.glRotatef(0, 1, 0, 0);

    Texture.bind();



        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
        //GL11.glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, S);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(S, S);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(S, 0);
        GL11.glEnd();


        GL11.glPopMatrix();

}
```

PS. I can understand a bit of pure OpenGL.

Comment: You only want one draw call for your entire scene? You may want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object . i.e. gather all your geometry and add it to frame buffer, then render the buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slowdown is not due to glBegin…glEnd, but the huge number of glNormal, glTexCoord, … glVertex calls inbetween. This is called immediate mode and has been out of fashion ever since OpenGL-1.1 was released, supporting Vertex Arrays. That was over 15 years ago.

Please use Vertex Arrays, preferrably in combination with Vertex Buffer Objects; that's where the real performance improvments come from.

Comment: could you please point me at some lwjgl tutorials for ding this.

Answer (score 1):

Immediate mode sends the draw calls to be rendered every frame already, you don't need to try to do that. I suggest you learn about vertex buffer objects, they group similar vertices together and send them to the GPU once per frame, and can be modified. They use floatbuffers for storage, and are the new way of rendering objects. For LWJGL tutorials, search TheCodingUniverse on youtube and look for his Advanced Rendering video, it will show you how to use VBOs.